# accessing resource property file in *.js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, struts2, resourcebundle

Hi my project is in struts 2. We have written common js files for client side validation.
now the problem is that to implement internalization we have to change alert message as per the language.
so my question is that is there any way to access resource property in js file.
or any one suggest some alternative or example for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Store the alert messages in js files with file names like

alert_en.js
alert_fr.js
alert_jp.js

In each file store the alerts like this

```
var ALERT_EMAIL_INCORRECT = "Incorrect email";
var ALERT_USERNAME_INCORRECT = "Incorrect username";
```

Include file as per the user languages.

OR

You can load messages from the resource bundle using a JSP file and link in your page like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="YOUR-FILE.JSP"></script>
```

In this JSP file you output JavaScript after reading from resource bundle.

Check [this](http://tishowicode.wordpress.com/2007/09/04/javascript-alert-messages-from-message-resource/) also.

Comment: This is a pretty good approach, but I would definitely encourage using an action backed by a JSP rather than a JSP directly. That keeps any processing that might need to occur out of the view layer.

Comment: Yes, take only JS design from me. Not sure about Java standards :)

Answer (score 2):

You can read properties file in js file using [messageResource.js](https://github.com/suhaibkhan/messageResource.js) library created by me.

1) Include messageResource.js in your html.

```
<script src="messageResource.min.js"></script>
```

2) You can access key-value pair of properties file from js as follows.

```
// initialize messageResource.js with settings
messageResource.init({
  // path to directory containing message resource files(.properties files),
  // give empty string or discard this configuration if files are in the
  // same directory as that of html file.
  filePath : 'path/messageresource/'
});

// will load the file 'path/messageresource/moduleName_en_US.properties'
// and callbackFunction will be executed when loading is complete.
messageResource.load('moduleName', callbackFunction, 'en_US'); 

// use messageResource.get function to get values from loaded file. 
var value = messageResource.get('key', 'moduleName', 'en_US');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a JSON file with the native English language as key and L10N message as the value, and use AJAX to load the related JSON depending on user's browser language configuration, and alert the message with alert(tanslatedTable[USER_LANG][ENGLISH_STRING])

Comment: Can you give any link where I find such example?

Comment: translatedTable = {"zh-CN" : {"hello" : "zh-CN hello zh-CN"}, "ja" : {"hello" : "ja hello ja"}}; When you want to alert a "hello" message, just alert(translatedTable[lang]["hello"]) is OK. Of course you can extend it to string's property, like an String.property.L10N() method, and then call it in this way: alert("hello".L10N());

Answer (score 0):

I do this in my javascript within script tags on the jsp pages :

```
<code>
    alert("<s:text name="amountMustBeNumeric"/>");
</code>
```

Works fine for me.